# SharePoint Development

Tags: development, development-enviroment

We are currently using SP 2019 in Classic view, with the intent to going to the modern views eventually. We're on premise and using SharePoint Designer and InfoPath for our development. Being these tools are being deprecated soon, what is the best/latest tools for replacing these?

Answer (score 1):

The best options you have:

**1. [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-support).**

You can use [the old version of SPFx](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37726.sharepoint-office-365-learning-popular-microsoft-virtual-academy-courses.aspx) to add customizations to SharePoint.

> SharePoint Server 2019 supports SharePoint Framework client-side web
> parts hosted on classic or modern SharePoint pages built by using the
> SharePoint Framework v1.4.1. SharePoint Server 2019 also supports
> SharePoint Framework extensions hosted on modern SharePoint pages
> built using SharePoint Framework v1.4.1. This means that when you're
> targeting the SharePoint Server 2019 platform, you need to use the
> SharePoint Framework v1.4.1 because of the server-side version
> dependencies.

2. **[SharePoint Push and Pull by Andrew Koltyakov](https://github.com/koltyakov/generator-sppp). [Or SPGo by Chris Hasz](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SiteGo.spgo)**.

The main advantage of the SPPP and SPGO approach is that it is the only type of customizaiton that can be migrated seamlessly. These are also supported with SP SP 2013, SP 2016. Unlike SPFx. The disadvantage is that you are using the CEWPs that are part of the classic UI. You also won't be able to use this approach on SharePoint Online sites where custom scripting is not allowed.

> SPPP generated projects suite perfectly for SPA development scenarios
> having local serve workbench with SharePoint API proxy server
> integrated from OOTB. Starting a local server your app refreshes
> instantly on changes using hot reload and incremental build at the
> same time the app is fully powered with real data from the API without
> any extra configuration.
>
> React, PnPjs, Office UI Fabric, TypeScript, SCSS, Linting rules,
> polyfills, Webpack bundling, Live server, SharePoint interactive
> connection, pipeline tasks, all of these just work from the start. The
> batteries are included, but maybe you need configuration changes? No
> problem, just override or provide yours, or extend a task, this is a
> part of the design.

**SPGo for Visual Studio Code**

SPGo allows you and your team to develop SharePoint web solutions from your local PC using the power of Visual Studio Code. Now you can build SharePoint sites and customizations source-control first with all of the power of a top-tier IDE. Produce cleaner code, deliver faster.

- Publish files on save
- Use VSCode compare tools to diff local changes against the server
- Pull down remote folders to your local workspace
- No more editors messing with your markup
- Support for: Windows, OSX, and Unix
- Keep all project configuration in Source Control for easy team integration

Comment: Denis, thank you for the quick response, I will look into all of these.

Comment: @Marker if you are already on SP 2019 and your intent is to eventually transition to modern experience, SPFx is pretty much the only way to go. The statement "The main advantage of the SPPP and SPGO approach is that it is the only type of customization that can be migrated seamlessly." is misleading at best, I think it may only be referring to backwards compatibility with SP 2013/2016.  SPFx works in 2019 classic, 2019 modern, and is forward compatible with SP Online should you eventually find yourself moving in that direction.

Comment: I knew this statement would cause some controversy, but using SPPP and SPGO is a nice transition from SharePoint Designer and InfoPath. The reality is that jumping from Designer to SPFx is not something power users and site owners can "just do". So it just does not happen often in the real life. Yesterday a site owenr was using Designer to teak some HTML. Tomorrow you say, "hey, why don't you use SPFx to do it?" Yes, CEWP is not "modern", but still very practical. And yes, it migrates seamlessly to SPO considering it's just part of the page

Comment: Are forms created with just HTML with the SP Framework?

Comment: You can't use SPFx for customizing list forms. If that's your question. SPFx is a bunch of compiled Javascript and HTML, stored in an App Catalog. Then these are exposed via a webpart you add to a modern page. You also can inject code via SPFx extensions. But it's not the best practice and it won't help you create forms.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov No, I guess my questions is what is the solution to replacing InfoPath.  Most of our apps have customized forms that users submit for requesting approvals for action items.

Comment: I would stick to InfoPath for now. Because you will be able to migrate it to the cloud. After migration to SPO you can start using Power Apps to customize list forms. SPFx is not a solution you can use to replace InfoPath. SPGo and SPPP can also be used, but it's not as user friendly as InfoPath in terms of List Item form customizations.

Comment: Therein lies the issue, we are government funded and per their stipulations we are not able to migrate to the cloud in the near future.  I'm pretty sure we can still use PowerApps without being fully in the cloud so I'll investigate that some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123516/discussion-between-denis-molodtsov-and-marker).